# How to create an EMF file from a MS Chart graph using a Stream

Tags: c#, mschart, memorystream, metafile

I am trying to create an **EMF** image from a **MS Chart** graph. I have got no problem using a `FileStream` to temporary store the image like this:

```cs
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("test.emf", FileMode.Create);
chart1.SaveImage(fileStream, ChartImageFormat.EmfPlus);
fileStream.Close();
Image emf = Metafile.FromFile("test.emf");
```

But if I try to get rid of the file using a `MemoryStream` I get a `System.ArgumentException`
HResult=0x80070057 (invalid parameter).

```cs
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
chart1.SaveImage(memoryStream, ChartImageFormat.EmfPlus);
Image emf = Metafile.FromStream(memoryStream);
```

I can't figure out why it is not working. I've read that the problem may be caused by the need to dispose the `Graphics` object. How can do it?

Comment: After writing to memory stream you must set position to zero before reading.

Comment: @jdweng Yes! I tried calling Flush() but didn't think to reposition the current position at the beginning. Thanks a lot!